# Convert Text to Number

Tags: postgresql

I have two table, with two colounms:

```
Tab1.Number1 (BigInt)
100000
100001

tab2.Number2 (character varying)
10000_300
10001_301
90009_222
```

I need to do a select that show the rows which have the same values (without  the '_').

i tried to convert the value with

`to_number(tab2.Number2, 99999)`

But it doesn't work:

```
to_number(character varying, integer) does not exist.
```

Database is postgress.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

try to replace the character '_' to '' before cast it to number

example:

```
cast(replace(tab2.Number2, '_', '') as int)
```

Comment: the cast doesn't work, and the replace it shows 90009 222.

Comment: try split it, split_part(tab2.Number2, '_', 1)